# export jconsole notification output to excel

Tags: java, csv, jconsole

I subscribe to notification in jconsole, for example for `PS Scavenge`.

I have the results in table but I can't copy/export them to excel:

[image]

Is there a way for save results found in jconsole in CSV/Excel format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in a slightly different format, but Java Mission Control (at `bin\jmc.exe` in the JDK), can subscribe to MBeans.

There you can expand and copy the notification results, including a (vertical) CSV option:

[image: Mission Control]

Comment: Does `Java Mission Control` have same (or more) features as jconsole?

Comment: The two overlap a great deal.  For MBeans the options are largely similar, elsewhere JMC is generally a bit more user friendly.

Comment: I can't connect to localhost using `JMC` as I succeeded with `jconsole` or `visualvm`

Comment: Annoying, they both use a JMX connection.  Could be JMC needs [extra permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48069887/1794485).  What error do you see?

Comment: Is there a reason of using `jconsole` over `JMC`?

Comment: Good question.  JMC came after jconsole, and largely supersedes it.  It's more actively maintained by Oracle.  That said a lot of people still use jconsole, it's probably more familiar to the community still.